# Why can't I build Python code from Sublime Text 3 when I launch it from Ubuntu Dash vs Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: python, text

when I launch the same Sublime Text 3 from Ubuntu Dash, I am not able to build Python Code, and I get the following error:

```
no such file or directory: ''
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -m py_compile ""]
[dir: /opt/sublime_text]
[path: /home/berk/bin:/home/berk/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your python path is not configured correctly. To fix:

Create a .bash_profile in your home directory. Then, add the line

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:new_dir
EXPORT $PYTHONPATH\
```

Or even better:

```
if [ -d "new_dir" ] ; then
    PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:new_dir"
fi
EXPORT $PYTHONPATH
```

The .bash_profile properties are loaded every time you log in.

The `source` command is useful if you don't want to log in again.